# Nested insertion respectively in two tables using commit and rollback in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, commit, rollback, raiserror

I am the beginner in sql server
I have to code to resolve the scenario that,

I have two tables. And I'm inserting record into those tables using a stored procedure. The stored procedure has the input parameters such as `@name`, `@age`, `@firstname` and `@lastname`.

I have to insert `@name` and `@age` into the first table (if condition age > 18). And `@firstname`, `@lastname` and `@age` into second table (if condition age > 20).

If any of the conditions or insertions failed means, all changes should be rollback else commit should occur.

My problem is only outer catch block raiserror only raised in all time.

Here is my code.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sample]
   @name varchar(10),
   @age int,
   @fn varchar(10),
   @ln varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @errormsg NVARCHAR(4000), @errormsg2 NVARCHAR(4000)


    BEGIN TRY
       IF(@age > 18)
       BEGIN
           BEGIN TRANSACTION 
                insert into employee 
                values(@name, @age)

                begin try
                   if(@age > 20)
                   begin
                      begin transaction
                          insert into empdet 
                          values(@fn, @ln, @age)

                          commit
                   end  
                   else
                   begin
                       RAISERROR (@errormsg2, 16, 1);
                   end
                end try
                begin catch
                    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                    begin
                         ROLLBACK
                    end

                    SET @errormsg2 = 'inner catch Error:Age is less than 20'
                    RAISERROR (@errormsg2, 16, 1);
                end catch   

                COMMIT
            END
            ELSE 
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR (@errormsg, 16, 1);
            END             
        end try
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            begin
                ROLLBACK
            end 

            SELECT @errormsg = 'Outer catch Error:Age is less than 18 '+cast(@age as varchar);
            RAISERROR (@errormsg, 16, 1);
        END CATCH
    END
```

Also point out any unnecessary code here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MitchWheat Sorry I could't get you. Actually I did not used any triggers here.

Comment: I meant use a check constraint, not a procedure, sorry.

Comment: Ok Mitch Wheat. But I have a condition to code using stored procedure only :-( .

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure about this code .just try it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sample]
@name varchar(10),
@age int,
@fn varchar(10),
@ln varchar(10),
AS
BEGIN
Declare @errormsg NVARCHAR(4000), @errormsg2 NVARCHAR(4000),
        @stmt1 varchar(1000), @stmt2 varchar(1000), @stmt3 varchar(1000),
        @stmt4 varchar(1000)    

BEGIN TRY
   IF(@age > 18)
   BEGIN
       BEGIN TRANSACTION 
            insert into employee 
            values(@name, @age)

            begin try
               if(@age > 20)
               begin
                  begin transaction
                      insert into empdet 
                      values(@fn, @ln, @age)

                      commit                           
               end  


               else
               begin
                   RAISERROR (@errormsg2, 16, 1);
                   ROLLBACK
               end
               End try
            COMMIT
               begin catch
                SET @errormsg2 = 'inner catch Error:Age is less than 20'
                RAISERROR (@errormsg2, 16, 1);
             end catch   


        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR (@errormsg, 16, 1);
        END             
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT @errormsg = 'Outer catch Error:Age is less than 18 '+cast(@age       varchar);
        RAISERROR (@errormsg, 16, 1);
    END CATCH
END
```